# Pdf change version using ghost script is not working

Tags: php, ghostscript

I want to change the pdf version to 1.4, I executed on `cmd` but it is giving me an error, I tried multiple solutions but getting the same error.

```
g`swin64 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dSAFER -sOutputFile=C:/temp_in/out.pdf C:/temp_in/pdf_in.pdf`
```

**Error**

> Error: /undefinedfilename in (C:/temp_in/pdf_in.pdf)
> Operand stack:
> Execution stack:
> %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval-
> -   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push
> Dictionary stack:
> --dict:733/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--
> Current allocation mode is local
> Last OS error: No such file or directory
> GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

**Error Screenshot**
[image: Error]

Comment: You are sure that pdf_in.pdf exists in the given directory? And btw: if you want to change to PDF version 1.4 why is `-dCompatibilityLevel=1.4` missing?

Comment: yes file exits and i tried to with this command "gswin64  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=C:/temp_in/pdf_out.pdf C:/temp_in/pdf_in.pdf"

Comment: it generated empty pdf file

Comment: Just tested it, I cannot reproduce your error, everything works fine for me. Are you really sure that `C:/temp_in/pdf_in.pdf` exists? Did you try it with another, very basic PDF?

Comment: @OcasoProtal buddy thank you, issue resolved actually the file name with extra ".pdf".